# componentDidMount unexpected token error [React.js]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently working on creating a PokeDex by using the PokeApi. I'm trying to complete the PokemonList, that will contain all the different PokemonCard buttons.

I am receiving `expected ";"` error for my `componentDidMount` and I'm unsure why.

The code for the page is

```
import React from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import "../ui/PokemonList.css";
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://pokeapi.co.api.v2.pokemon/",
    pokemon: null
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  const res = axios.get(this.state.url);
  this.setState({pokemon: res.data['results'] });
}


const PokeList = () => {
  return (
    <section className="poke-list">
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
    </section>
  );
};

//export default PokeList;
```

It is marking the error on the `{` symbol after `componentDidMount()`.

The error remains there, even after I add a semi-colon after the curly brackets, even though I don't think the semi-colon is necessary, since the guide I'm following doesn't do it.

Is there some simple rule that I'm breaking? I'm new to React / JavaScript.

edit ----------------------------------------------------

My Dashboard.Js code is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import PokeList from "../pokemon/PokemonList";

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <PokeList />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error now

```
./src/components/layout/Dashboard.js
Attempted import error: '../pokemon/PokemonList' does not contain a default export (imported as 'PokeList').
```

Comment: You have typo, your `PokemonList` is getting closed after `state` only which should get closed at the end.

Comment: @ravibagul91 can you clarify what you mean? the error stays even after I remove the semi colon

Comment: Not the semicolon, you have closing `}` after state which closes your class.

Comment: Where you want to use `PokeList` component?

Comment: @ravibagul91 I want use to PokeList on my dashboard page, because It's being displayed within a smaller div

Comment: You should have it in separate file and import wherever required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably because

```
import React from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import "../ui/PokemonList.css";
import axios from 'axios';

export default class PokemonList extends Component {
state = {
  url: "https://pokeapi.co.api.v2.pokemon/",
  pokemon: null
};
} <----- extra curly brace remove this

componentDidMount() {
  const res = axios.get(this.state.url);
  this.setState({pokemon: res.data['results'] });
}

//keep this function inside class
PokeList = () => {
  return (
    <section className="poke-list">
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
    </section>
  );
};

   render() {
   return(
   <div>{this.Pokelist}</div>
)
}}
//export default PokeList; // <=== remove this
```

Your component did mount was outside the class component.

to make your current code work --

```
import React from "react";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";
import "../ui/PokemonList.css";
import axios from 'axios';

export const PokemonList = class PokemonList extends Component {
  state = {
    url: "https://pokeapi.co.api.v2.pokemon/",
    pokemon: null
  };


componentDidMount() {
  const res = axios.get(this.state.url);
  this.setState({pokemon: res.data['results'] });
}
} <==== class component ended

export const PokeList = () => {
  return (
    <section className="poke-list">
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
      <PokemonCard />
    </section>
  );
};
```

Dashboard js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {PokeList} from "../pokemon/PokemonList";

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <PokeList />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This should work if i got what you wanted to do. If you wanted to make pokemonList and pokelist totally different components then that's different. Tell me what you wanted then i'll change my answer accordingly.

Comment: Removing the "export default PokeList" gives me an error on the const PokeList code

Comment: From what I'm figuring out, I can not export two defaults in the same chunk of code?

Comment: You can't export two different components as default from same file.

Comment: no you can only export once. so only at the top on bottom choose one

Comment: Then how would I be able to export the PokemonList and PokeList? Since I need both of them.

Comment: I would suggest keep pokeList inside PokemonList if pokeList is using the state of PokemonList.

Comment: You can just say export and then while importing destructure it .. `Import {PokemonList, PokeList} from "./file"`

Comment: @AtinSingh can you expand on what you mean with this? apologies for not understanding too well.

Comment: expand on what? My suggestion or how to export two components?

Comment: About exporting and destructuring the two components

Comment: Edited my answer see if this works. I never tried exporting two components before but this works with variables so i think this should work.

Comment: Export normally instead of using export default.

Comment: @AtinSingh would I create a new file and write that code in it? Or where exactly do I import this?

Comment: No.. just use the import statement as i wrote wherever you want to import. it's the same idea as what you do with importing `import React , { Component } from 'react''`.. Just import them like this. use curly braces when you haven't exported with default.

Comment: After working through some errors, the final one I'm getting now is "PokeList is declared, but it's value is never read".

Comment: @AtinSingh I've made the changes and the initial errors seem to have gone, I edited my question to show my dashboard.js and the error that's being thrown now.

Comment: Yeah the import was in correct in your dashboard js. Also i don't see you making use of your PoekmonList class component anywhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199682/discussion-between-zadders-and-atin-singh).

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is invalid url.

Change url with: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/

See code example:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import PokemonList from "./components/PokemonList";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PokemonList />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import PokemonCard from "./PokemonCard";

class PokemonList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      url: "https://pokeapi.co.api.v2.pokemon/",
      pokemons: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    axios
      .get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/")
      .then(response => {
        const data = response.data.results;
        this.setState({ pokemons: data });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };

  render() {
    const { pokemons } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="pokemon-list">
        {pokemons.length > 0 &&
          pokemons.map(pokemon => {
            return <PokemonCard pokemon={pokemon} />;
          })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PokemonList;
```

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class PokemonCard extends Component {
  render() {
    const { pokemon } = this.props;
    console.log(pokemon);
    return (
      <div className="pokemon-card">
        <p>Name: {pokemon.name}</p>
        <p>
          Url: <a href={pokemon.url}>{pokemon.url}</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default PokemonCard;
```

[image: Edit pokemon example]